# c++ endless loop reading file created redirecting command output

Tags: c++, command, output

I'm writing a code in which I check a given directory for new files or directories. New in my situation is regarded to last time the code has been run in that directory. So I create a log file and then I acquire the log in a string vector. The code is the following:

```
ifstream Finp;
string directory;
vector <string> newfilelist;

system( ("ls -B "+directory+" > "+directory+"filelist.log").c_str() );
Finp.open( (directory+"filelist.log").c_str() );
while ( true ) {
  string stmp;
  Finp >> stmp;
  if( Finp.eof() ) break;
  newfilelist.push_back( stmp );
}
```

Now what's happening is the following:

1) if the log "filelist.log" already exists, everything runs smoothly

2) if the log "filelist.log" does not exist, it is correctly created but when the code opens the file and starts acquiring it, it gets stuck in a loop and the stmp string is endlessly empty (as if the file has no eof() and yet is empty!). what is intresting is the fact that if I place a random system command before opening the log everything runs smoothly!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think that, the only thing you would need to change is that nasty `while(true)` loop to `while(file<< to_variable)`. This would only read data IF there is some.

The `eof()` is actually quite deceiving. You would guess that it is called right at the end of the file. Though true, when you try to read from the file at the `>>` operation the pointer in the stream will jump back before the `EOF` and try to read what is there.

There is quite the few threads here discussing just `EOF` and using that as a condition for a loop.

Answer (score 0):

If the file does not exist, `Finp.open()` will basically fail, and checking `Finp.eof()` is meaningless. Before even attempt to enter a loop to read or check eof, you need to check the `Finp` status with `Finp.good()` and then proceed with reading only if this method returns true.